# My potho is turning brown look like it’s burned

Tags: houseplants

My potho is turning brown and yellow what could be the cause of this[image]

Answer (score 1):

Too much water causes the soil to be saturated. Air is not available to the roots and this changes the environment from ideal for roots to perfect for fungus/virus/bacteria.  This is an infection that healthy plants can outgrow.

- reduce water
- do not let the plant sit in water
- increase the light levels
- remove leaves that have the black spots